# Data or table in datagridview is not show c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to create a table in datagridview and add a text. I try many of the codes but it does not work.

Here the output even I program to adding some text:

[image: datagridview output]

Add columns from cart form:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
    private void domainUpDown1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
table.Columns.Add("BOOK", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Author", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(double));
        table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
```

and add rows from book form:

```
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
DataTable TBL = new DataTable();
        TBL.Rows.Add(BName2.Text);
        TBL.Rows.Add(AName2.Text);
        TBL.Rows.Add(PRC2.Text);
        Ct.dataGridView1.DataSource = TBL;
}
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: You are adding columns to `DataTable table`. But in `button6_Click` you are adding rows to `DataTable TBL`. I suppose you should use the same `table`.

Comment: I did that, but also not work

Comment: As Alexander points out… you are creating a “NEW” `DataTable` `TBL` in the `button6_Click` click event. I am confident when you click the button… the code will crash because the `DataTable` `TBL` has no columns.